# How do I make a character creator that can create variations of the same character? (see post)

Tags: python, function, class

This is my first question BTW.
So I have been having this problem with a program in Python, I am making a Character class that is able to make characters with different stats, abilities, etc. The class works perfectly fine, but the problem is; I don't know how to make variations of a character. 
For example,

```
class Char:
    def __init__(self, HP, attack):
        self.HP = HP
        self.att = attack

Tom = Char(5, 7)
Bill = Char(6, 6)

player1 = Tom
player2 = Tom

print player1.HP, player2.HP
#prints out 5, 5
player1.HP = 3

print player1.HP, player2.HP
#prints out 3, 3
```

If I could make variations of a character, it would print out 3, 5 on the last part.
I figure this can be fixed with another class or a function, but I don't know how. Help?

Answer (score 0):

You have a memory issue. When you assign `player1 = Tom`, `player1` gets a reference to `Tom`, same with `player2`, which means `player1.HP` is actually changing `Tom`. Instead what you want to do is `from copy import deepcopy` at the top of your script and then say `player1 = deepcopy(Tom)` and then `player2 = deepcopy(Tom)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you print `id(player1)` and `id(player2)`, you'll see they point to the same object, which is why changes are synchronized. If you want to create variations, as you called them, you can use the `copy` module:

```
>>> import copy
>>> player2 = copy.copy(Tom)
>>> player2.HP = 3
>>> print player1.HP, player2.HP
5 3
```

See also the distinction between shallow and deep copy, in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html), which also explains why this is necessary:

> Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create
>   bindings between a target and an object. For collections that are
>   mutable or contain mutable items, a copy is sometimes needed so one
>   can change one copy without changing the other.